# Launcher Minimized Window

Tags: 13.04, launcher, window, minimize

I open a windows and minimize it. Then, I want to open the minimized window so I click on the Files icon on the launcher but It opens `/home/user` again.

How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

well that issue I was faced and solution is simple , instead of left click, choose right click on the files from there you can choose minimized files.

@OP I cant give you precise screen shot because right now I am using my work PC , but the process is same. Just right click on the files , from there you can do opening minimized files.

[image]

Comment: The windows that I minimized is not there.But if I click the icon and open a new Windows, It appears.

Comment: you just look at the bottom menu , there you can find it,.

Comment: As I said, I appears when there are two windows. Check this: http://i.imgur.com/JgJO3UP.png

Comment: @g2d yes that means you have already opened home. I mean its saying that 101 and home are two opened windows. why dont you give a try by closing home and keeping 101 only, :)

Comment: Not in there : http://i.imgur.com/SHfQQwc.png

Comment: ok Now open only 101 and not any other . @g2d

Comment: In the picture above only 101 is opened.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11242/discussion-between-rajagenupula-and-g2d)